# Kusto query Past 7days off each day log count with respect to timestamp

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm not expect in kusto query can some one help me out this.

I need past 7days of each day log count with respect to timestamp off table.

Like today is Wednesday log count - 50
Tuesday log count - 105
Monday log count - 65 ...

Like that past 7 days of each day results.

If we assume today date is 9/9/22. I need 8/9/22 to 2/9/22 logs count off each day.

Last 7 days each day count expecting in kusto query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you could try this:

```
TableName
| where Timestamp >= startofday(ago(7d))
| where Timestamp < startofday(now())
| summarize count() by startofday(Timestamp)
```

result example:

| Timestamp | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-02 00:00:00.0000000 | 2269683165695 |
| 2022-09-03 00:00:00.0000000 | 1950416520792 |
| 2022-09-04 00:00:00.0000000 | 1921780739235 |
| 2022-09-05 00:00:00.0000000 | 2161205348826 |
| 2022-09-06 00:00:00.0000000 | 2294524001765 |
| 2022-09-07 00:00:00.0000000 | 2351404246099 |
| 2022-09-08 00:00:00.0000000 | 2386512393024 |

Comment: Can we extract with the same command with specific message like in logs status code is 200 ok, status code is unauthorized 400 not ok, can we extract the count of 200 and 400 per day and per week, per month

Comment: your question is unclear (to me). try providing a sample input data set, and the expected result, in order to clarify it

Comment: In table message column I have data like 200 ok, 400 unauthorized messages with date wise data I'm getting when I ran the table name command. Now I need to retrieve the last week each day of 200 count, 400 count required

Comment: Table name
| Where message has "200 ok" now I need last week  each day off count. Who may are 200 ok, 400 unauthorized count required